# Open Application after minimized in android

Tags: android, minimize, android-homebutton

I have an android application , when user press home button ,android application minimize . I want to open this application 5 seconds after minimize.
what should I do?

Comment: you need one parent activity ( baseActivity ), then override onPause and onResume, run one handler in onPause, then check, if after 5 second onResume not called, run every method that you want.

Comment: it's true, but I write onResume() in onPoause method , that does not work , what should I write in onPause?

Comment: how your wrote `onResume()` in `onPoause` ? can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code i wrote for you

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 123, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000,pendingIntent);
}
```

If you want exactly 5 seconds in devices after KitKat use alarmManager.setExact

Comment: Implement exactly,if using android 4.4+ use setExact method. atleast upvote answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlarmManager` for that. You have to create an new alarm in your `onPause` activity method. This alarm will fired a `Intent` for opening your application again.

Documentation: [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)